# Custom CSS not loading on WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am building a custom WordPress theme and am having issue with linking to my CSS. Using `<?php  get_template_part( 'template-parts/template-header' ) ?>` at the top of all of my templates (such as my homepage, which lives at `template-parts/template-homepage`, I am grabbing the header I have built. In the head of my header HTML I have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css"/>`.

To ensure it's not something like a relative path issue, I've also placed my css files within template parts. When I preview the page my HTML is there, but no CSS. Any thoughts as to why this might be?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't use `<link>` tags in wordpress to load a CSS, you should use `wp_enqueue_style` & other relative functions to enqueue a style. Second, `homepage.css` is not a complete path of css, you need to provide the complete path of css here. also `type="text/css"` is missing from link tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hardly posted any code, so it's impossible to give you clear instructions, but in general, you should *enqueue*  all style sheets in your `functions.php` file, using the `wp_enqueue_style()` function.

Here are links to two pages which tell you more about this:

1.) A more technical description: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

2.) A more tutorial-like description:  https://learn.wordpress.org/lesson-plan/enqueueing-scripts-and-styles/

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'll be sure to post more details next time. Is it possible to enqueue all of my style sheets and assign each one to its specific template partner? (about.css to template-about.php, homepage.css to template-homepage.php and so on)?

Comment: I would rather use *one*  stylesheet where you have combined selectors which include the page-specific `body` class of that page/post, like `.home main .mydiv1 .etc {...}`

Comment: @lukej it is _possible_ but unless your stylesheet is causing performance issues, it's not worth splitting it up like that